# KeyboardAvoidingView create a permannat offset and i cant scroll to to after

Tags: react-native

I had to add KeyboardAvoidingView to my view since, i have text inputs. The thing is that the keyboardVerticalOffset is working well. But after that when i want to scroll to the top again it is impossible. It missing the keyboardVerticalOffset.

```
const DismissKeyboard = ({children}) => (
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
      behavior={"position"}
    >
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            {children}
        </View>  
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</ScrollView>
```

);

[image]

When i should be able to scroll to this point :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs with Android.
The solution is to use this as offset:

```
const offset = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? -200 : 0;
```

And then use :

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={offset}
      behavior={"position"}
    >
```